# Using list comprehension to number dataframes in a list of dataframes

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a list of 4 dataframes, called df.
I'd like to add a "number" column to each dataframe (df[i]['number']) that represent the dataframe number.

I tried to use list comprehension for that:

```
df=[df['number']=(x+1) for x in range(0,4)]
```

Which resulted in

```
   File "<ipython-input-52-0b708f543fbb>", line 1
   df=[df['number']=(x+1) for x in range(0,4)]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried:

```
df=[x['number']=(y+1) for x,y in enumerate(df)]
```

With the same result, pointing at the '=' sign.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

**1)**

```
In [454]: df = [x.assign(number=i) for i, x in enumerate(df, 1)]

In [455]: df[0]
Out[455]:
          0         1  number
0  0.068330  0.708835       1
1  0.877747  0.586654       1

In [456]: df[1]
Out[456]:
          0         1  number
0  0.430418  0.477923       2
1  0.049980  0.018981       2
```

Good part you can assign it to a new variable without altering old list like

```
dff = [x.assign(number=i) for i, x in enumerate(df, 1)]
```

**2)**

If you want inplace and list comprehension

```
In [474]: [x.insert(x.shape[1] ,'number', i) for i, x in enumerate(df, 1)]
Out[474]: [None, None, None, None]

In [475]: df[0]
Out[475]:
          0         1  number
0  0.207806  0.315701       1
1  0.464864  0.976156       1
```

Comment: Uff... assign is nifty but certainly not cheap... why is your answer the only one which got upvoted ;-(

Comment: What does mean cheap here ?

Comment: @jezrael _very_ space efficient... `assign` creates copies

Comment: There you go, inplace and list comprehension!

Comment: It's certainly not pretty... using a list comp to produce side effects, but kudos :p

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - hmmm. I think if somebody says - my solution is faster, better is get timings. Because sometimes man can be wrong (maybe here not, in another solution yes)

Comment: 'pretty' is a personal taste. assign and list compre is prettier than for loop with indented assignment personally. ;-)

Comment: list comprehensions shouldn't be used for side-effects. If you are going to use them, you should create a new data-frame. If you are going to mutate, use a for-loop.

Comment: @jezrael Added timings. I couldn't time John's second solution however (the side effects caused problems with timeit), so I only timed the assign one.

Comment: Nice, could you add a note on memory footprint aswell?

Comment: I can't back that up with numbers ( I don't know how!) so I just wrote a line on it.

Comment: I know assign creates a copy (hence more space). And, having numbers on the post would help others when they come here, whenever you find out a way to add the numbers, please do.

Comment: Thanks, I do like the "elegant" one lined list-comprehension solution, but I learn a lot from the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Use `enumerate`, starting from 1 and assign to each dataframe in your list.

```
for i, d in enumerate(df, 1):
    d['number'] = i
```

In-place assignment is *much* cheaper than assignment in a list comprehension.

---

```
df[0]
   id  marks
0   1    100
1   2    200
2   3    300

df[1]
    name  score flag
0  'abc'    100    T
1  'zxc'    300    F


for i, d in enumerate(df, 1):
    d['number'] = i

df[0]
   id  marks  number
0   1    100       1
1   2    200       1
2   3    300       1

df[1]
    name  score flag  number
0  'abc'    100    T       2
1  'zxc'    300    F       2
```

---

**Performance**

## Small

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 278 µs per loop # mine
```

vs

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 567 µs per loop # John Galt
```

## Large (*`df * 10000`*)

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 607 µs per loop # mine
```

vs

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.16 ms per loop # John Galt - assign
1 loop, best of 1: 1.42 ms per loop # John Galt - side effects
```

Note that the loop-based assignment is also space efficient.